# Select by last relation or no relation

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a relation between task and operations. I want to select the manual tasks without operation OR with a action != 'cancelled' for the last operation.

Example

```
tasks table :
-------------
|id | state |
| 3 |auto   |
| 5 |manual |
| 6 |manual |
| 2 |manual |
| 8 |manual |

operations table :
----------------------------------
|id | action    | task_id | time |
| 1 | processed | 8       | 8:00 |
| 2 | cancelled | 8       | 9:00 |
| 3 | processed | 6       | 8:00 |
| 4 | processed | 2       | 8:00 |
| 5 | cancelled | 2       | 7:00 |

result : tasks 5,6,2
```

Here is what I managed to do :

```
SELECT tasks.*
WHERE tasks.id NOT IN(
    SELECT operations.task_id)
OR tasks.id IN
    SELECT operations.task_id
    WHERE action!=cancelled
    .....
    .....
    ORDER BY time DESC
```

I am not sure how to end this query. Also it will perform 2 query on operations for each line in tasks.

Comment: Are you willing to rely on "cancelled" being the last action for each task that has any such action at all?

Comment: Yes, i want No operation, or a cancelled last operation.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  To put it another way, if there is a 'cancelled' operation for a given task, can there be any subsequent operations for that task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say this is your schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tasks (
    id int unique,
    state text
);

CREATE TABLE operations (
    id serial,
    action text,
    task_id int REFERENCES tasks (id),
    time text
);

INSERT INTO tasks (id, state) VALUES (3, 'auto');
INSERT INTO tasks (id, state) VALUES (5, 'manual');
INSERT INTO tasks (id, state) VALUES (6, 'manual');
INSERT INTO tasks (id, state) VALUES (2, 'manual');
INSERT INTO tasks (id, state) VALUES (8, 'manual');

INSERT INTO operations (action, task_id, time) VALUES ('processed', 8, '8:00');
INSERT INTO operations (action, task_id, time) VALUES ('cancelled', 8, '9:00');
INSERT INTO operations (action, task_id, time) VALUES ('processed', 6, '8:00');
INSERT INTO operations (action, task_id, time) VALUES ('processed', 2, '8:00');
INSERT INTO operations (action, task_id, time) VALUES ('cancelled', 2, '7:00');
```

This would be your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tasks
WHERE state = 'manual' AND
      (
        NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM operations WHERE task_id = tasks.id LIMIT 1)
        OR
        (SELECT action FROM operations WHERE task_id = tasks.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1) != 'cancelled'
      )
;
```

Output:

```
 id | state  
----+--------
  5 | manual
  6 | manual
(2 rows)
```

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.  I'm thinking `distinct on` to get the information about the operations:

```
select distinct on (task_id)
from operations o
order by task_id, time desc;
```

Then a `left join` to get the tasks:

```
select t.*
from tasks t left join
     (select distinct on (task_id)
      from operations o
      order by task_id, time desc
     ) o
     on o.task_id = t.task_id
where o.task_id is null or o.action <> 'cancelled';
```

Comment: Does the distinct query return only the last operation?

Comment: @Syl . . . It returns the last operation for each task.  `distinct on` usually has better performance than `row_number()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to rely on 'cancelled' being the last operation performed on a task if ever it is performed -- that is, if cancellation puts a task in a terminal state, then don't need to focus on cancellation being the *last* operation, only on whether there is a cancellation at all.

In that case, you can use a fairly simple outer join to find your result:

```
select t.*
from
  tasks t
  left outer join operations o
    on t.id = o.task_id
       and o.action = 'cancelled'
where t.state = 'manual' and o.id is null;
```

Note in particular the `o.id is null` in the filter condition -- supposing that 'id' is the primary key for table `operations`, it can be null in the joined result only where no row of `operations` satisfies the join condition for a given row of `tasks`.  That is, only for tasks that have no associated 'cancelled' operation (including those with no operations at all).

On the other hand, if you need to include tasks that have a 'cancelled' operation, but for which the *last* operation is something different, then you might use a window function to help you identify the last operation for each task:

```
select t.*
from
  tasks t
  left outer join (
      select
        operations.*,
        max(operations.time) over (partition by task_id) as last_time 
      from operations
    ) o
    on t.id = o.task_id
      and o.action = 'cancelled'
      and o.time = o.last_time
where t.state = 'manual' and o.id is null;
```

It is essential here that the `o.time = o.last_time` appear in the join condition, not a filter condition of the inline view (where it would be illegal) or the filter condition of the outer query (where it would have the wrong effect).